# ¿Como puedo capturar el valor siguiente de una busqueda en una cadena de php?

Tags: php

Me explico. Estoy usuando PDFParser con codeigniter. Al subir una factura al sistema me rescata toda la informacion de dicha factura mo texto en una variable llamada content, quiero realizar una busqueda dentro de esa variable para que me devuelva en numero de la factura. por ejemplo: se que dentro del texto esta Nº, y quiero que la busqueda me devuelva lo que viene despues de ese dato. Como lo podria hacer maestros? TT_TT, llevo mucho tiempo intentando diferentes cosas y nada funciona.

Comment: Hola Cesar. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes mostrar las *"diferentes cosas que has probado y nada funciona"*? Sobre eso podremos ver que está mal, y como puedes mejorarrlo. Muestra un ejemplo del contenido de la variable. Has probado con `indexOf` (o similar) o con Regex? Mira [ask] para mejorar la pregunta.   Un saludo

Comment: Buenas Cesar. Usa la opción de "Editar", justo debajo de los tags de tu pregunta, para añadir nueva información o aclaraciones.

Comment: no podia editar, esto me imprime la variable $content : CONTACTO: R.U.T.:76.222.222-1 FACTURA ELECTRONICA Nº18490 S.I.I. - CHILLAN Fecha Emision: 01 de Septiembre del 2017.

Al utilizar strstr() asi: 
$n_factura = strstr($content, "Nº");
        echo $n_factura.'<br>';
Me devuelve desde el N° todo hacia delante, y no puedo colocarle un limite para que solo me muestre los 6 primeros caracteres. Tengo que extraer cada parte de la informacion de una factura en diferentes variables para almacenarlas, pero no me sale. Gracias por la ayuda e iluminacion.

Comment: Dale a editar, has de poder. Y dices que *"no te sale"*  pero no dices **qué has probado**. Muestranos tus intentos para ver qué haces mal y mejorarlo.

Comment: pude hacer algo que me devuelve el resultado que quiero, es un poco largo, pero sirve. 
   1.  $n_factura = strstr($content, "Nº");
        echo $n_factura.'<br><br>';
   2.  $numero = strstr($n_factura, "S.I.I", true);
        echo $numero.'<br><br>'; 
   3.  $numero_de_factura = str_replace('Nº', '', $numero);
        echo $numero_de_factura;
Lo que hize fue lo siguiente:
  1. Me captura todo el resultado desde N° hacia delante (Nº18490 S.I.I. - CHILLAN)
  2. Me captura desde S.I.I. hacia atras y se la paso a otra variable.(Nº18490 ).
 3: Al final elimino el N° y obtengo el numero.

Comment: Cesar. **Primero** lee el [tour]. No puedes esperar que te ayudemos si no sabes como funciona este sitio. **Segundo**, dale a [edit] para añadir esa informacion, no uses los comentarios para explicaciones. Si has encontrado respuesta, publicalo en la seccion de respuestas siguiendo [answer].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos modos bastantes simples de extraer la información que necesitas, tomaré solo un fragmento del texto.

```
$x = 'CONTACTO: R.U.T.:76.222.222-1 FACTURA ELECTRONICA Nº18490 S.I.I. - CHILLAN Fecha Ess 5452';
$pos = strpos($x, 'Nº'); // Encuentras la posición donde está el número
$substr = substr($x, $pos+3,strlen($x)); // Recortas la cadena para empezar desde el número que buscas.
$arr = str_split($substr); // Conviertes en array
$num = '';
foreach($arr as $v) // Opción 1
{
    if(is_numeric($v))
    {
        $num .= $v;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}

echo $num."\n"; //18490

$anotherWay= $arr[0].$arr[1].$arr[2].$arr[3].$arr[4]; // Opción 2 si la longitud del número nunca cambia.

echo $anotherWay; //18490
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con las lineas de arriba me diste la pauta para solucionarlo. Mil gracias. :)